# Is it possible to send keys to browser on locked user?

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, foreground

I have made very simple script.
All it does, is that it sends an escape key to a browser:

```
WebDriver webDriverInstance = handl.browser;
webDriverInstance.manage().window().maximize();
webDriverInstance.switchTo().window(webDriverInstance.getWindowHandle());
handl.waitFor(500);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Only problem is that this code stops working when windows user running script gets locked.
Is there a possibility, that when windows user gets locked, there is no such thing as foreground anymore or what may be the issue?

All the help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you using robot when Action class can perform this for you

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
```

It will not affect on locked machines

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have tried this before and it did not work at all for some reason

Comment: I was also thinking, that I could click cancel button, but popup I am trying to close is not javascript one, but rather server request.